# Difference between requestAnimationFrame and requestAnimFrame

Tags: webgl, pixi.js

There seems to be a little documentation on this but i'm wondering what the difference is between the two? They seem to be the same (?) in `Pixi`

Comment: You can refer to the previous discussions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053223/window-requestanimframe-clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`requestAnimFrame` is a JavaScript [polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) to implement `requestAnimationFrame` for browsers that don't yet support `requestAnimationFrame` or for browsers that still prefix it.

See http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ for one of the first implementations of `requestAnimFrame`.

Comment: Could you tell me why every one is using teh JavaScript polyfill (`requestAnimFrame`) over `requestAnimationFrame` ? Does it use `requestAnimationFrame` if the browser supports WebGL?

Comment: It's historic. When the polyfill was made not all browsers that supported WebGL supported `requestAnimationFrame`. Now they all do so there's no reason for `requestAnimFrame` for any browsers that support WebGL AFAIK. Some common samples use it, people just keep copying the samples and so it lingers