# WebGL requestAnimFrame()

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I have a number of 3D objects inside the canvas and am looking to implement the requestAnimFrame() function on only one of these (a cube). The other items must not be affected and should remain static. The render function looks like this:

```
function render()
{
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 2.0;
    gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    // Render cube
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    requestAnimFrame( render );
}
```

If I added the other objects to this function, e.g.

```
// Render sphere
gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, points.length );
```

they will rotate together with the cube.

Question: do I create a separate render function for the static objects? I assme I can exclude a second call to

```
 gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

because the buffers don't need a second clearing? Or am I missing something and is there another way from preventing the other objects from moving?

Comment: You dont have to complicated it. One way you can do it is to keep the matrix separated on the shader (projection, camera, obj. transformation). So you can call update the transformation and call drawArrays for the respective object.

Comment: window.requestAnimFrame should be forget altogether. [Just mind about window.requestAnimationFrame.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053223/window-requestanimframe-clarification?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Don't update the position/rotation/scale data for those objects. You only want to use one requestAnimationFrame method in your application.

gl.clear(); simply clears the specified buffer, painting on top of the screen with the color in `gl.clearColor()`. Then when you call drawArrays() next time, be sure to only move the a cube, and don't move or rotate the other objects in the scene, they just get re-drawn in the same spot.