# Having trouble with program flow - juggling between AJAX callbacks and rendering PIXI JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm having trouble making my js script flow smoothly. It's a script that receives and sends mouse co-ordinates and draws them.

Here it is:

```
//Initialize PIXI
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x000000);
var renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(1600, 900);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

//requestAnimFrame(animate);
function animate() {
    console.log("Draw.");
    requestAnimFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(stage);
}

//Function for receiving data.
indx = 0;
var makeRequest = function(){
   var ajaxFunction = function(){
      if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        var pointsStr = ajaxRequest.responseText.split("C"); //The co-ordinates are received in this form: "pointCpointCpointCpoint...pointCindex"
        indx = parseInt(pointsStr[pointsStr.length - 1]);
        for (i = 0; i < pointsStr.length - 1; i++) {
            if(pointsStr[i] != ""){
                var points = pointsStr[i].split(",");
                mouseX = parseInt(points[0]);
                mouseY = parseInt(points[1]);

                var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics(); //Why create new graphics every time? PixiJS bugs out if I don't. Probably also something to do with the flow.
                graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFFFF);
                stage.addChild(graphics);
                graphics.drawRect(mouseX,mouseY,1,1);
                renderer.render(stage);
                console.log("Received.")
            }
        }
      } 
   }
   var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = ajaxFunction;
   ajaxRequest.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/receiveData/0=" + indx, true);
   ajaxRequest.send();
}

//Function for sending data.
var sendRequest = function(arr){
   var t = ""
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        t += arr[i].x.toString() + "," + arr[i].y.toString() + "C";
   }
   t = t.slice(0,-1);
   var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   ajaxRequest.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1/sendData/" + t, true);
   ajaxRequest.send();
   console.log("Send.")
}

pos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

var mouseRecording = new Array();

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
    var p = pos;
    p.x = e.clientX || e.pageX; 
    p.y = e.clientY || e.pageY;
    mouseRecording.push(pos);
    console.log("" + p.x + "," + p.y)
}, false);

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    console.log("Make Request.");
    sendRequest(mouseRecording);
    makeRequest();
}, 100);
```

Basically, the problem is that the flow is really inconsistent.

For example it'd just POST and GET for 10 seconds with no callback being run, but then suddenly 200 requests would run subsequently, and then maybe once in a blue moon the screen would render etc.

What is the correct way here to make the program flow adequately?

Comment: Forget about the requestAnimFrame experimental polyfill, now is the time for a real requestAnimationFrame polyfill: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053223/window-requestanimframe-clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes on function naming and responsibilities: 1. If your function has a really generic short name and a comment right above it that says something different, then get rid of the comment and rename your function. 2. Your function should only do what it says it does it does, and nothing more. 3. Your function should not modify its parent scope. Side effects make debugging difficult.

That said, let's start by breaking this out into a whole bunch of tiny functions that do so little, they can't possibly do anything wrong. And named so that they don't do anything else.

```
//Initialize PIXI
var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x000000);
var renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(1600, 900);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

function httpRequest(method, url, success, fail) {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 ) {
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
        success(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
      else {
        fail();
      }
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open(method, url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function getRequest(url, success, fail) {
  httpRequest('GET', url, success, fail);
}

function postRequest(url, success, fail) {
  httpRequest('POST', url, success, fail);
}

function buildDataStringFromCoords(coords) {
  return coords.map(function(coord) {
    return coord.x.toString() + ',' + coord.y.toString();
  }).join('C');
}

function buildCoordsFromDataString(dataString) {
  return dataString.split('C').map(function(coordString) {
    var points = coordString.split(',');
    return {x:+points[0], y:+points[1]};
  });
}

function renderCoords(coords) {
  var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics(); //Why create new graphics every time? PixiJS bugs out if I don't. Probably also something to do with the flow.
  graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFFFF);
  stage.addChild(graphics);
  graphics.drawRect(coords.x, coords.y, 1, 1);
  renderer.render(stage);
}

function requestCoords(indx, success, fail) {
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/receiveData/0=' + indx;
  getRequest(
    url, 
    function(response) {
      var coords = buildCoordsFromDataString(response);
      success(coords);
    },
    function() {
      fail();
    }
  );
}

var sendCoords = function(coords, success, fail) {
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/sendData/' + buildDataStringFromCoords(coords);
  postRequest(
    url,
    function() {
      success();
    },
    function() {
      fail();
    }
  );
}

pos = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};

var mouseRecording = new Array();

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){ 
  var p = pos;
  p.x = e.clientX || e.pageX; 
  p.y = e.clientY || e.pageY;
  mouseRecording.push(pos);
  console.log('Mouse moved', p.x, p.y);
}, false);

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  console.log("Make Request.");
  sendCoords(
    mouseRecording,
    function() {
      console.log('Successfully sent coords', mouseRecording);
    },
    function() {
      console.log('Failed to send coords', mouseRecording);
    }
  );
  requestCoords(
    indx,
    function(coords) {
      console.log('Successfully fetched coords', coords);
      coords.forEach(function(coord) {
        renderCoords(coord);
      });
      console.log('Rendered coords', indx);
    },
    function() {
      console.log('Failed to get coords', indx);
    }
  );
}, 100);
```

This now lets us write some tests to prove that each part is "correct", so you don't have to step through the entire big thing every time something goes wrong. For example:

```
function testBuildDataStringFromCoords() {
  return buildDataStringFromCoords([{x:123,y:456},{x:987,y:654}]) === '123,456C987,654';
}
```

This might not completely fix the issues you have, but I hope it makes your life easier and will make the issue more transparent.